# how do i get my application to run i created it using eclipse on my desktop but it will not run on my laptop?

Tags: java, css, eclipse

```
package gui;



import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.RadioButton;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Controller {

    private FXMLLoader medicalRcord;
     Pane pane;
     Stage stageMedicalRecord;
     Stage stageAppointmentClerk;
     Stage stageMedicalStaff;
     Stage stageAdminClerck;

    @FXML  private RadioButton medicalRecord;
    @FXML  private RadioButton appointmentClerk;
    @FXML  private RadioButton medicalStaff;
    @FXML  private RadioButton adminStaff;
    @FXML  private TextField password;


public void selectedMedicalRecord (ActionEvent event){

        System.out.println("This work");

        //medicalRecord.setSelected(true);
        appointmentClerk.setSelected(false);
        medicalStaff.setSelected(false);
        adminStaff.setSelected(false);

    }

public void selectedAppointmentCleck (ActionEvent event){

    System.out.println("This work");

    medicalRecord.setSelected(false);
    //appointmentClerk.setSelected(true);
    adminStaff.setSelected(false);
    medicalStaff.setSelected(false);

}

public void selectedMedicalStaff (ActionEvent event){

    System.out.println("This work");

    medicalRecord.setSelected(false);
    appointmentClerk.setSelected(false);
    medicalStaff.setSelected(true);
    adminStaff.setSelected(false);

}

public void selectedAdminStaff (ActionEvent event){

    System.out.println("This work");

    medicalRecord.setSelected(false);
    appointmentClerk.setSelected(false);
    medicalStaff.setSelected(false);
    adminStaff.setSelected(true);
}



public void handleNext( ActionEvent event){

    System.out.printf( "It is listening" );


    try {
        if(medicalRecord.isSelected()==true && password.getText().equalsIgnoreCase("1")){

        stageMedicalRecord = new Stage();


        medicalRcord = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("medicalRcord.fxml"));
        medicalRcord.getController();

        Parent pane = medicalRcord.load();

        stageMedicalRecord.setTitle("Medical Record Specialist ");
        stageMedicalRecord.setScene(new Scene(pane, 1000, 600));
        stageMedicalRecord.show();
        stageMedicalRecord.setX(500);

        }

        if(appointmentClerk.isSelected()==true && password.getText().equalsIgnoreCase("2")){
            stageAppointmentClerk = new Stage();
            pane = new Pane();
            stageAppointmentClerk.setTitle("Admission or Appointment Clerk ");
            stageAppointmentClerk.setScene(new Scene(pane, 600, 600));
            stageAppointmentClerk.show();
            stageAppointmentClerk.setX(500);

            }

        if(adminStaff.isSelected()==true  && password.getText().equalsIgnoreCase("4")){
            stageAdminClerck = new Stage();
            pane = new Pane();
            stageAdminClerck.setTitle("Administrative Staff ");
            stageAdminClerck.setScene(new Scene(pane, 600, 600));
            stageAdminClerck.show();
            stageAdminClerck.setX(500);
            }

        if(medicalStaff.isSelected()==true && password.getText().equalsIgnoreCase("3")){
            stageMedicalStaff = new Stage();
            pane = new Pane();
            stageMedicalStaff.setTitle("Medical Staff ");
            stageMedicalStaff.setScene(new Scene(pane, 600, 600));
            stageMedicalStaff.show();
            stageMedicalStaff.setX(500);
            }

       } 

        catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}




}
```

code above is to run a dummy application for my capstone class when i ran it last night on my desktop it ran fine but now on my laptop in eclipse it will not run and i imported from the desktop eclipse has the jdk installed but i dont know what else could it be i am lost for words

Comment: What happens when you try to run it?

Comment: How is this related to [tag:css]?

Comment: i wold post the rest of the code that has the css b ut it would not let me.

Comment: /* JavaFX CSS - Leave this comment until you have at least create one rule which uses -fx-Property */


.title{
 
 -fx-font-size: 40px;
 -fx-fill: Black;
 -fx-alignment: left;
}

.label{
 
 -fx-font-family: Times New Roman;
  
}

.dale{
 -fx-font-family: Times New Roman;
 -fx-font-size: 20px;
 -fx-fill: Black;
 -fx-text-alignment: left;
 
}

.text-field{
 
 -fx-font-family: Times New Roman;
 -fx-font-size: 18px;
}
.dale1{
 -fx-font-family: Times New Roman;
 -fx-font-size: 15px;
 -fx-fill: Black;
 -fx-text-alignment: left;
 
}

Answer (score 0):

Stupid question but do you have the JRE on your laptop? If so make sure your environment path variable is correct. Go to the bin directory in the JRE or JDK file and copy the directory to the path variable.

OR, 
Try jar the file as a runnable jar file or make sure the manifest file is correct. Hope this works